Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List'
I made a project that separate backend and frontend and this is the frontend the backend is alright, the problem is when i POST a data using form always get that problem this is my raw Code

Guest.java

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Guest {
    private Integer id;
    private String nama;
    private String alamat;
    private String noTelepon;
    private String keterangan;
    private LocalDateTime waktuKunjungan;
    private List<Event> events;
}


GuestRequest

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GuestRequest {
    private String nama;
    private String alamat;
    private String noTelepon;
    private String keterangan;
    private String waktuKunjungan;
    private List<Integer> eventsId;
}


GuestCreateRequest.java

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GuestCreateRequest {
    private Integer id;
    private String nama;
    private String alamat;
    private String noTelepon;
    private String keterangan;
    private String waktuKunjungan;
    private List<Event> events;
}


This is the service

 public GuestRequest createDTO(GuestRequest guestRequest){
        HttpEntity<GuestRequest> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<GuestRequest>(guestRequest);
        return restTemplate
                .exchange(
                    url, 
                    HttpMethod.POST, 
                    httpEntity,
                    GuestRequest.class
                    ).getBody();
    }


and this is the controller

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pendaftaran")
public class registGuest {
    
    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;
    
    @Autowired
    private GuestSerivce guestSerivce;

    @GetMapping
    public String getPendaftaran(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("title", "pendaftaran user");
        model.addAttribute("guestCreateRequest", new GuestCreateRequest());
        model.addAttribute("events", eventService.getAll());
        return "user/formGuest";
    }

    

    @PostMapping
    public String create(Model model, @ModelAttribute("guestCreateRequest") GuestCreateRequest guestCreateRequest,
                         @RequestParam(name = "eventList") Set<Integer> eventList, BindingResult bindingResult,
                         RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes ){
        try {
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                model.addAttribute("title", "pendaftaran user");
                model.addAttribute("guestCreateRequest", new GuestCreateRequest());
                model.addAttribute("events", eventService.getAll());
                return "user/formGuest";
            }

            GuestRequest guestRequest = convertToGuestRequest(guestCreateRequest, eventList);
            guestSerivce.createDTO(guestRequest);
            return "redirect:/user/daftarTamu";
        } catch (Exception e) {
           model.addAttribute("errors", "Something wrong");
           
        }
        return "redirect:/user/formGuest";
    }

 private GuestRequest convertToGuestRequest(GuestCreateRequest guestCreateRequest, Set<Integer> eventList ){
        GuestRequest guestRequest = new GuestRequest();
        guestRequest.setNama(guestCreateRequest.getNama());
        guestRequest.setAlamat(guestCreateRequest.getAlamat());
        guestRequest.setKeterangan(guestCreateRequest.getKeterangan());
        guestRequest.setNoTelepon(guestCreateRequest.getNoTelepon());
        guestRequest.setWaktuKunjungan(guestCreateRequest.getWaktuKunjungan());
        guestRequest.setEventsId(new ArrayList<>(eventList));
        return guestRequest;
    }

}

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='guestCreateRequest'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'guestCreateRequest' on field 'events': rejected value [3]; codes [typeMismatch.guestCreateRequest.events,typeMismatch.events,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [guestCreateRequest.events,events]; arguments []; default message [events]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'events'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.guestbook.clientApp.model.entity.Event' for property 'events[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


And what is your question?
